# Using Pandas to create DataFrame with Series, resulting in memory error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm using Pandas library for remote sensing time series analysis. Eventually I would like to save my DataFrame to csv by using chunk-sizes, but I run into a little issue. My code generates 6 NumPy arrays that I convert to Pandas Series. Each of these Series contains a lot of items

```
>>> prcpSeries.shape
(12626172,)
```

I would like to add the Series into a Pandas DataFrame (df) so I can save them chunk by chunk to a csv file.

```
d = {'prcp': pd.Series(prcpSeries),
     'tmax': pd.Series(tmaxSeries),
     'tmin': pd.Series(tminSeries),
     'ndvi': pd.Series(ndviSeries),
     'lstm': pd.Series(lstmSeries),
     'evtm': pd.Series(evtmSeries)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
outFile ='F:/data/output/run1/_'+str(i)+'.out'
df.to_csv(outFile, header = False, chunksize = 1000)
d = None
df = None
```

But my code get stuck at following line giving a Memory Error

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Any suggestions? Is it possible to fill the Pandas DataFrame chunk by chunk?

Comment: Can you make a DataFrame from a single column: pd.DataFrane({'tmax': pd.Series(tmaxSeries)})?

Comment: create a frame with the first series, and add them sequentially, e.g. ``df = DataFrame({'prcp' : pd.Series(prcpSeries) }); df['tmax'] = pd.Series(tmaxSeries)``. You should probably write it to a HDF5 in any event, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables

Comment: @Jeff I was wondering if that might work, but wasn't sure how to test it... (need [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3871) ;) )

Comment: When you are passing a dict (even if the values are Series), I think copies are made. If you do iteratively (and argument is a series), then no copy

Comment: @Jeff I've cobbled something together... I think I prefer using an outer concat tbh.

Comment: yep...prob a better solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you know each of these are the same length then you could create the DataFrame directly from the array and then append each column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(prcpSeries, columns=['prcp'])
df['tmax'] = tmaxSeries
...
```

---

Note: you can also use the [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) method (which allows you to (optionally) pass a name - which is useful if the Series doesn't have one):

```
df = prcpSeries.to_frame(name='prcp')
```

---

However, if they are variable length then this will lose some data (any arrays which are longer than `prcpSeries`). An alternative here is to create each as a DataFrame and then perform an outer join (using [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html)):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(prcpSeries, columns=['prcp'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tmaxSeries, columns=['tmax'])
...

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, ...], join='outer', axis=1)
```

For example:

```
In [21]: dfA = pd.DataFrame([1,2], columns=['A'])

In [22]: dfB = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=['B'])

In [23]: pd.concat([dfA, dfB], join='outer', axis=1)
Out[23]:
   A   B
0  1   1
1  2 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Andy and Jeff! I've to use the first method with appending each column, since the second approach gets an Memory Error at the line of df = pd.concat(etc.). I know the series with the longest length and will use that one to initialise the DataFrame.

Comment: One caveat: I'm using pandas version 0.14.1 and when I try to coerce a Series object to a DataFrame object, if I specify `columns = ['my_column_name']` in the `pandas.DataFrame()` call, the resulting object is an empty DataFrame. When I dropped the columns argument, the resulting DataFrame was as expected.

Comment: @Jubbles Thanks for mentioning this, perhaps it's cleaner to use the `to_frame` method here (I'm not sure this was available when I wrote the original answer) - I've updated this answer to mention that. I will have a look to see if this no longer works in 0.14+, I will have a check later to see.